# How to CSS colour alternate div rows without using ngFor index

Tags: css, angular

I am using ngFor to display data, but it is sorted by display criteria and not index.  How can I display alternate div row colours based on the sorted display results instead of index?

The problem is that if I use index, the 1st 4 results might be even, the next 3 odd, etc - not alternating.

```
<div *ngFor="let year of activityYears">
 <div class="bold">{{year}}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let activity of activityData; let index = index">
   <div *ngIf="activity.activityYear === year">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" fxLayoutGap="10px">
     <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start start"  fxLayoutGap="10px">
      <div class="width-80px" [ngStyle]="{'color':seasonColour(activity.activitySeason)}">{{activity.activitySeason}}</div>
      <div class="width-200px bold" [ngStyle]="{'color':roleColour(activity.character)}">{{activity.character}}</div>
      <ng-container *ngIf="!isEditing"><div [ngStyle]="{'color':covenantServiceColour(activity.covenantService)}">{{activity.activity}}</div></ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="isEditing && this.idEdit === activity.activityID"><div [ngStyle]="{'color':covenantServiceColour(activity.covenantService)}" class="width-500px"><mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="fill-container"><mat-label>Activity</mat-label><input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="activityEdit" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></mat-form-field></div></ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="isEditing && this.idEdit === activity.activityID"><div><mat-checkbox [checked]="activity.covenantService"  #covServCheckbox (change)="covServiceSelect($event, activity.activityID, activity.activityYear, activity.activitySeason, activity.activitySeasonID, activity.character, activity.activity, activity.characterRole)">Covenant Service</mat-checkbox></div></ng-container>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use `nth-child(even){...}` within your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use CSS pseudo class `nth-child` that allow you to select "odd" and "even" elements.

So whatever is your order of elements, it will always be the odd ones with some css and the even one with other.

Like this for example

```css
.row:nth-child(odd){
  background-color:gray;
}

.row:nth-child(even){
  background-color:light-gray;
}
```